# Reprojecting Mars image from SimpleCylindrical to Equirectangular projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mars

The task is to re-project the image of Mars from one projection to another. In particular I want to re-project an image from SimpleCylindrical Mars projection - Projected to Equirectangular MARS projection - Projected.

I am trying to do this in QGIS. In general, any free software will be Ok, but QGIS / gdal is preferrable.

There is a mosaic of several images in the target projection Equirectangular MARS - Projected, for which QGIS detects Equirectangular MARS - Projected
Extent for files of this mosaic different - but this is expected. In WKT format, the information for one of them looks like this

```
PROJCRS["Equirectangular MARS",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_MARS",
        DATUM["unnamed",
            ELLIPSOID["unnamed",3394839.8133163,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Reference meridian",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Equidistant Cylindrical",
            ID["EPSG",1028]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",15,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",180,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Proj4
+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=15 +lon_0=180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=3394839.8133163 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
Extent
Extent not known
```

And there is a source image in the SimpleCylindrical Mars - Projected projection for which the following information is available in WKT format

```
PROJCRS["SimpleCylindrical Mars",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_Mars",
        DATUM["D_Mars",
            ELLIPSOID["Mars",3396190,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Reference_Meridian",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["Equidistant Cylindrical",
        METHOD["Equidistant Cylindrical",
            ID["EPSG",1028]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",180,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Proj4
+proj=eqc +lat_ts=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=180 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=3396190 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs
Extent
Extent not known
```

So the task is to re-project the original SimpleCylindrical into the target Equirectangular MARS

How I try to do this in QGIS:

Raster -> Projections -> Warp

Further, in the Target CRS dropdown, QGIS offers me just to select the target Equirectangular MARS. After that, the gdal command looks like this

`gdalwarp -t_srs "PROJCRS[\"Equirectangular MARS\",BASEGEOGCRS[\"GCS_MARS\",DATUM[\"unnamed\",ELLIPSOID[\"unnamed\",3394839.8133163,0,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]]],PRIMEM[\"Reference meridian\",0,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,ID[\"EPSG\",9122]]]],CONVERSION[\"unnamed\",METHOD[\"Equidistant Cylindrical\",ID[\"EPSG\",1028]],PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",15,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",180,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",0,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],PARAMETER[\"False easting\",0,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],CS[Cartesian,2],AXIS[\"easting\",east,ORDER[1],LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]],AXIS[\"northing\",north,ORDER[2],LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]]]" -r near -of GTiff D:\Work\basemap4\cartOrder\g13_023168_1986_xn_18n282w.tiff AppData/Local/Temp/processing_kYcVhc/de2acc95a18744c68c6075b5cad27744/OUTPUT.tif`

Everything works without errors and the original raster "jumps" closer to the mosaic of rasters, but still it "sits" in the wrong place.
Obviously, the problem is how to specify the correct parameters in the gdal command (I suspect it's all about the values ​​for lat / long).

Can you tell me how to do this correctly?

Comment: Your process seems correct to me. If you just load both layers in a map or project defined at any of both CRSes, can you see that one layer is in the wrong place?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Yes, when I load both layers in a map, I see source raster (already reprojected to Equirectangular projection) in a wrong place. Even though it is close to where is shoud be, it is still in a wrong place

Comment: So I think that reprojection will not take any of them to the right place. Source data or source CRS definition of any of them may be wrong.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca But there has to be some way to "stick" together!

Comment: If the problem is not with the radius of the sphere in the datum I don't know, may be just reproject and georeference one to stick to the other.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca you mean, I should use GCP to georeference it?

Comment: I think you should see if there is a problem with the coordinate reference system definition of one of both datasets, and if you can't find any problem there and you want to see them aligned, you can georeference one to the other. The only way to georeference is marking GCPs.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Thanks for your advice. There should be no problem with the coordinate systems for both datasets, cause I take it directrly from the data provider. And tbh, I do not know how to check if there are some problems. 
Anyway, for now I just decided to georeference image using GCP. That solved for now the problem